# debian no space left on /var/tmp

Tags: debian

I do have a small x86 embedded device (pc engines ALIX 2d13) that i would like to install debian on it. I did found an image from `http://blog.alexolivan.com/jessie4alix/` and i placed it in the CF card. the system boots fine but when i do `apt-get updat`e and `apt-get upgrade` it does send the following error:

```
    .....
cp: error writing ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dl0AO4/lib/klibc-f2PiCYYs54qvkiXqpXzqc...’: No space left on device
cp: failed to extend ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dl0AO4/lib/klibc-f2PiCYYs54qvkiXqpXzqc...’: No space left on device
cp: error writing ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dl0AO4//bin/kmod’: No space left on device
cp: failed to extend ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_dl0AO4//bin/kmod’: No space left on device
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/kmod failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-586 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@alix:/home/alixadmin# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1 7.4G 986M 6.1G 14% /
udev 10M 0 10M 0% /dev
```

if i reboot the system then i am loosing access to it. `apt-get autoremove` keeps trying to reinstall the failed packages. the path /var/tmp says that it is 100% full.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Your `df` command says that `/` has 6.1 GB free which is much more than you normally need for creating new initramfs images. My compressed images are around 50 MB:

```
$ ls -lh /boot/initrd.img-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51M Jan  7 17:36 /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-21-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51M Jan 12 00:07 /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-25-generic
```

So 250 MB should probably be enough for creating a new initrd. Are you sure that `/var/tmp` is on `/dev/sda1` and not on a tmpfs mount or a different partition? To free disk space you could run `apt-get clean` to clear out the local repository of retrieved package files or you could cleanup `/tmp`.